# WPF, Xaml and Controls Factory?

Tags: wpf, design-patterns, xaml

I'd like to create WPF control which consists of few another controls. The main problem is how implement choosing right control depending on Model's type?

```
<MyControl>
<!-- if DataContext.GetType() == Type1 -->
<Control1 DataContext = {Binding}/>
<!-- if DataContext.GetType() == Type2 -->
<Control2 DataContext = {Binding}>

</MyControl>
```

How can i implement and design it well? My idea was to put there something like...

```
Control CreateControl(object dataContext) {
 if (dataContext.GetType() == TYpe1)
     return new Control1() {DataContext = dataContext}
 if (dataContext.GetType() == TYpe2)
     return new Control2() {DataContext = dataContext}    
}
```

But i don't know how can i invoke such method, which returns Control inside XAML...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define `DataTemplates` in the resources, and use a `ContentControl` as a placeholder

Resources:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:Model1}">
    <Control1 />
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:Model2}">
    <Control2 />
</DataTemplate>
```

(note that you don't need to explicitly set the `DataContext`)

Usage:

```
<MyControl>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" />
</MyControl>
```

It will pick the appropriate `DataTemplate` based on the type of the `Content`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [DataTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx) for that case.